# How to change the functionality of a button so that it can work as the backspace button

Tags: keyboard, backspace

Okay, so I have a Compaq laptop [American keyboard].
It is a few days that the backspace button is broken - I mean, it is totally popped off. It ought to be replaced but it is hard to find it out.

Now, I was wondering whether or not there was a way to change the functionality of another button so that it can replace the functionality of the backspace button.

**It is not the DEL button. It is the BACKSPACE button [above the Enter button].**

I knew that through some binary numbers it is possible to change the functionality of a button. For example, I can change the DEL button in the Number Lock so that instead of working as DEL button or dot, it will work as backspace.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you can't. You can use the accessibility screen keyboard for urgency situations, but I recommend you to buy another keyboard.

Comment: Take a look at Autohotkey.

Comment: look here at another question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190813/flex-button-acting-like-a-backspace?rq=1

how can i do that?

Comment: The question seems that it belongs to superuser.com. Currently I'm on mobile, not able to flag.

Comment: i downloaded and installed Hotkeys software ....how can i use it?
what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on windows, you may use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), install it, create a file with `.ahk` extension and put following code in it.

```
F1::Send {BackSpace}  ; Makes the 'F1' key send 'BackSpace' key.
```

Then run the above script on startup.

More Details for remapping [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Another way on Ankit's recommendation:

After installing the AutoHotkey, creating the short script and saving it with .ahk extension, just put the file in the startup folder :) click Start(or windows logo)---All Program---startup  folder  :) then re-start pc.